# gcc compiling assembly on ubuntu

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, compiler-errors, x86-64

On my first assignment of the course we've been asked to try compile a simple assembly file on Ubuntu terminal using the following line:

```
gcc Hello.s
./a.out
```

Here the code inside the file:

```
#This is a simple "Hello World!" program
    .section    .rodata #read only data section
str:    .string "Hello World!\n"
    ########
    .text   #the beginning of the code
.globl  main    #the label "main" is used to state the initial point of this program
    .type   main, @function # the label "main" representing the beginning of a function
main:   # the main function:
    pushq   %rbp        #save the old frame pointer
    movq    %rsp,   %rbp    #create the new frame pointer

    movq    $str,%rdi   #the string is the only parameter passed to the printf function (remember- first parameter goes in %rdi).
    movq    $0,%rax
    call    printf      #calling to printf AFTER we passed its parameters.

    #return from printf:
    movq    $0, %rax    #return value is zero (just like in c - we tell the OS that this program finished successfully)
    movq    %rbp, %rsp  #restore the old stack pointer - release all used memory.
    popq    %rbp        #restore old frame pointer (the caller function frame)
    ret         #return to caller function (OS)
```

but after the compilation this is what printed on the terminal:

```
"/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccm5BVMG.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' 
     can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"
```

I've looked on the web for the problem and tried compile it with the flag, but still nothing.

Comment: Please don't post code as image. To fix the code, use `lea str(%rip), %rdi`. I am guessing ubuntu uses PIE by default, you could also try to use `-fno-pie -fno-PIE` options to gcc but that 32 bit absolute addressing is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Ubuntu, not OS X?  Or rossibly Ubuntu has changed the default to making position-interdependent executable to enable ASLR.  What Ubuntu and gcc versions?  (include output of `gcc -v Hello.s`)